# Re-arrange column order in mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have a 2-column layout (C1 & C2).

Inside C1 I have 3 boxes (B1, B2 & B3).

Inside C2 I have 1 box (B4).

On mobile view I would like to make the vertical order of the boxes: B1-B2-**B4**-B3.

How can this be done? I'm open to using flex box, but find the syntax a bit confusing.

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to take one DIV from second parent and put it into first parent using styles only, looks like you need to preload different markups depending on a mobile / desktop view, there was a project where we used http://masonry.desandro.com/ to rearrange columns according to the view but it was really pain in the ass so I would preload needed markup and simply show / hide it depending an a screen size :)

Comment: This is something you can do with CSS grids, but it will be a few years before that works in most browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible without using flex... The effect you described can be achieved (but not using the HTML structure you mentioned)- adjust the HTML structure and put B3 inside C2, then position B4 between C1 and C2.

[Pen here](http://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/EjgzNX)

```css
body {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
  .c1, .c2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.b1 {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
}
.b2 {
  background: dodgerblue;
  height: 100px;
}
.b3 {
  background: turquoise;
  height: 100px;
}
.b4 {
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .c1, .c2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .b4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="b1">.b1</div>
  <div class="b2">.b2</div>
</div>
<div class="b4">.b4</div>
<div class="c2">
  <div class="b3">.b3</div>
</div>
```